# How to change readable permission to writable permission in android emulator

Tags: android, linux, android-emulator, platform

I am working in emulator to connect in localhost. For some reason, I need to change the locahost network connectivity. I received the localhost file from System and moved to say for eg: C:/temp/host location. In the host file, I edited and again I tried to move to System/etc/hosts but it fails to move the file. It display the error as couldnt create file: Read-only file system. Please suggest me solution.

Below are the Steps followed:

1. C:\Users\Android\sdk\platform-tools> adb pull /system/etc/hosts C:/temp/hosts

   [100%] /system/etc/hosts
2. The file has been successfully moved to temp folder.
3. After I edited the file, I tried to push. But it fails.
4. C:\Users\Android\sdk\platform-tools>adb remount
   Not running as root. Try adb root first
   C:\Users\Android\sdk\platform-tools> adb root
5. C:\Users\Android\sdk\platform-tools> adb push C:\temp\hosts\system\etc

   ***adb error: failed to copy 'C:\temp\hosts' to '/system/etc/hosts': couldn't create file Read only file system.***

Answer (score 0):

You must do "adb remount" after "adb root", after you can do the push.

Comment: ok, instead of remount, could you try : adb shell mount -o rw,remount /system

Answer (score 0):

```
adb root

adb disable-verity

adb reboot

adb root 

adb remount
```

and the run the

```
adb push .....
```

you may see error like this because of all the reboot and roots

```
error: no devices/emulators found
```

just run this command

```
adb devices
```

you will see something like this

```
List of devices attached
0123456789ABCDEF        device
```

and then try it again.